# Datameer 5.0 latest edition

Tags: java, json

Please tell me how to download the datameer 5.0 and installation on vmware i m doing thesis on this the installation guide not gives the succesful result, i just want to use free trial and if any  sample data anybody have regarding fraud detection plj share it. asps

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to a free trial of Datameer here: http://www.datameer.com/free-trial/

Also, if there are specific issues with installation, I'd recommend sharing any errors in the Datameer Community directly here: https://community.datameer.com That's actively monitored by regular Datameer users, they can help out with any specific errors you may encounter.

In the Datameer App Market, they have examples of Credit Card Fraud and Anti Money Laundering applications that include some sample data sets. That is a good place to start with sample data.

Comment: Thanks i m trying on it